# How do I add a post route to my react application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a modal with the following code in my components and I would like to add a post route to my code to capture the user's response. I have Mongo/Mongoose set up as well as a backend server. Any help would be amazing as I am new to React!

```js
render() {
  return(
   <div className="modal column y-center">
    <h3>How are you doing?</h3>
    {!this.state.start ? (
     <div className="choices">
      <button onClick={() => this.startRelaxation('ok_images')}>Ok</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.startRelaxation('neutral_images')}>Neutral</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.startRelaxation('anxious_images')}>Anxious</button>
     </div>
    ) : (
     <div className="column y-center">
      <div className="image">
       <img src={this.state[this.state.mood][this.state.current_image]}/>
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.nextImage.bind(this)}>Next Image</button>
     </div>
    )}
    <button onClick={this.props.closeModal}>Close</button>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: What does `this.startRelaxation` do? That's where you should be making the POST call to store their answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response I have attached the startRelaxation function below. Any help would be wonderful.

this.state = {
   start: false,
   current_image: 1,
   mood: '',
   ok_images: [
    'https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=16',
    ],
   neutral_images: [
    'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=103',
   ],
   anxious_images: [
    'https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=16',
    
   ]
  }
 }

 startRelaxation(mood) {
  this.setState({
   start: true,
   mood: mood
  });
 }

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend hooking up your `startRelaxation()` function to execute a HTTP request to your backend using a 3rd party library such as [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Alternatively, given you are using MongoDB, you may find a database management tool such as [Parse Server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is just building off of Arman's post, but you can do something like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class YouComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.startRelaxation = this.startRelaxation.bind(this);
        }
        startRelaxation(string){
            axios.post('YourRoute'{'BODY OF REQUEST'})
            .then(data => 'DO STUFF WITH DATA');
        }
        render() {
            return(
                <div className="modal column y-center">
                    <h3>How are you doing?</h3>
                    {!this.state.start ? (
                        <div className="choices">
                            <button onClick={() => this.startRelaxation('ok_images')}>Ok</button>
                            <button onClick={() => this.startRelaxation('neutral_images')}>Neutral</button>
                            <button onClick={() => this.startRelaxation('anxious_images')}>Anxious</button>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className="column y-center">
                            <div className="image">
                                <img src={this.state[this.state.mood][this.state.current_image]}/>
                            </div>
                            <button onClick={this.nextImage.bind(this)}>Next Image</button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                    <button onClick={this.props.closeModal}>Close</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

You have the axios request in the startRelation method and you can do whatever you need to do in the DB.